# Making two balls move in android

Tags: android

Iam a new-bee to android development.I got the code for a ball movement from a site.It has MovementView.java and UpdateThread.java classes.On the same lines I tried to make two balls moving by defining classes MovementView1.java and UpdateThread1.java but Iam getting only the second ball moving and also can someone please tell how to make balls deflect when then clash against each other.

This is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.movements;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MovementView(this));
    setContentView(new MovementView1(this));
}
}
```

This is MovementView.java

```
package com.example.movements;
public class MovementView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private int xPos;
private int yPos;
private int xVel;
private int yVel;
private int width;
private int height;
private int circleRadius;
private Paint circlePaint;
UpdateThread updateThread;
public MovementView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    circleRadius = 10;
    circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    xVel = 2;
    yVel = 2;
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawCircle(xPos, yPos, circleRadius, circlePaint);
}
public void updatePhysics() {
    xPos += xVel;
    yPos += yVel;
    if (yPos - circleRadius < 0 || yPos + circleRadius > height) {
        if (yPos - circleRadius < 0) {
            yPos = circleRadius;
        }else{
            yPos = height - circleRadius;
        }
        yVel *= -1;
    }
    if (xPos - circleRadius < 0 || xPos + circleRadius > width) {
        if (xPos - circleRadius < 0) {
            xPos = circleRadius;
        } else {
            xPos = width - circleRadius;
        }
        xVel *= -1;
    }
}
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Rect surfaceFrame = holder.getSurfaceFrame();
    width = surfaceFrame.width();
    height = surfaceFrame.height();
    xPos = width / 2;
    yPos = circleRadius;
    updateThread = new UpdateThread(this);
    updateThread.setRunning(true);
    updateThread.start();
}
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    updateThread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            updateThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is MovementView1.java

```
package com.example.movements;
public class MovementView1 extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private int xPos;
private int yPos;
private int xVel;
private int yVel;
private int width;
private int height;
private int circleRadius;
private Paint circlePaint;
UpdateThread1 updateThread;
public MovementView1(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    circleRadius = 10;
    circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    xVel = 50;
    yVel = 50;
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawCircle(xPos, yPos, circleRadius, circlePaint);
}
public void updatePhysics() {
    xPos += xVel;
    yPos += yVel;
    if (yPos - circleRadius < 0 || yPos + circleRadius > height) {
        if (yPos - circleRadius < 0) {
            yPos = circleRadius;
        }else{
            yPos = height - circleRadius;
        }
        yVel *= -1;
    }
    if (xPos - circleRadius < 0 || xPos + circleRadius > width) {
        if (xPos - circleRadius < 0) {
            xPos = circleRadius;
        } else {
            xPos = width - circleRadius;
        }
        xVel *= -1;
    }
}
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Rect surfaceFrame = holder.getSurfaceFrame();
    width = surfaceFrame.width();
    height = surfaceFrame.height();
    xPos = width / 2;
    yPos = circleRadius;
    updateThread = new UpdateThread1(this);
    updateThread.setRunning(true);
    updateThread.start();
}
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    updateThread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            updateThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is UpdateThread.java

```
package com.example.movements;
public class UpdateThread extends Thread {
private long time;
private final int fps = 20;
private boolean toRun = false;
private MovementView movementView;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
public UpdateThread(MovementView rMovementView) {
    movementView = rMovementView;
    surfaceHolder = movementView.getHolder();
}
public void setRunning(boolean run) {
    toRun = run;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (toRun) {
        long cTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if ((cTime - time) <= (1000 / fps)) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                movementView.updatePhysics();
                movementView.onDraw(c);
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
        time = cTime;
    }
}
}
```

This is UpdateThread1.java

```
package com.example.movements;
public class UpdateThread1 extends Thread {
private long time;
private final int fps = 20;
private boolean toRun = false;
private MovementView1 movementView;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
public UpdateThread1(MovementView1 rMovementView) {
    movementView = rMovementView;
    surfaceHolder = movementView.getHolder();
}
public void setRunning(boolean run) {
    toRun = run;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (toRun) {
        long cTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if ((cTime - time) <= (1000 / fps)) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                movementView.updatePhysics();
                movementView.onDraw(c);
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
        time = cTime;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have done the movement of two balls but can someone please tell me how to make two balls deflect when they collide.

Comment: Check for "Android Dev" videos on YouTube :  "http://www.youtube.com/user/androiddevelopers?feature=watch" . Maximum you'll get an Idea